SwiftUI 3rd level of .sheet() disappears immediately
In MacCatalyst on MacOS Sonoma 14.6 when my app has 3 levels of active sheets the 3rd sheet disappears immediately after presenting, if the 1st level  sheet is a modifier on a view in the NavigationStack, rather than a modifier of the NavigationStack. I don't have this problem in MacCatalyst on MacOS 13.6, on iOS 16.4 or on iOS 17.6. In my real app each one of these NavigationStacks has many sheets, hence the use of the overlays. What's the right way to make this work on iOS > 16 and macCatalyst on MacOs > 14.6? Thank you
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestSheetsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popup1Item = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Popup 1") {
                popup1Item = true
            }
            // this code results in the 3rd level of sheet disappearing after presenting
            .overlay(
                EmptyView()
                    .sheet(isPresented: $popup1Item) {
                        Popup1()
                    }
                )
        }
        // this code results in the 3rd level of sheet staying after presenting
        /*
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
                .sheet(isPresented: $popup1Item) {
                    Popup1()
                }
            )
        */
    }
}

struct Popup2: View {
    @State var showPopup3 = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Popup 3") {
                showPopup3 = true
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
                .sheet(isPresented: $showPopup3) {
                    Text("Popup 3")
                }
        )
    }
}

struct Popup1: View {
    @State var popup2Item = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Popup 2") {
                popup2Item = true
            }
            .overlay(
                EmptyView()
                .sheet(isPresented: $popup2Item) {
                    Popup2()
                }
            )
         }
    }
}


I don't understand why you have the sheets in overlays using EmptyView()?
Even if you have a NavigationStack with many sheets.
Have you tried moving them out? (works for me)

Hi, you’re right. It seems all sheets have to be done either inside or outside of navigationstacks. If you post the answer i will accept it. Thank you

Here is my test code with the .sheet outside of the .overlay
and NavigationStack. Works well for me, tested on macOS and macCatalyst.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var popup1Item = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("ContentView")
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Popup1") { popup1Item = true }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $popup1Item) { Popup1() }
    }
}

struct Popup1: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var popup2Item = false
    @State private var sheetx = false
    @State private var sheety = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Popup1")
        Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Popup2") { popup2Item = true }
            Button("Show sheetx") { sheetx = true }
            Button("Show sheety") { sheety = true }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $popup2Item) { Popup2() }
        // other sheets
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetx) { SheetX() }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheety) { SheetY() }
    }
}

struct Popup2: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var showPopup3 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Popup2")
        Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Popup3") { showPopup3 = true }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPopup3) {
            Text("Popup3")
            Button("Go back Popup2") { showPopup3 = false }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetX: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Text("SheetX")
        Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }
    }
}

struct SheetY: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Text("SheetY")
        Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }
    }
}

Note, that you could also use a NavigationStack(path: ...) and .navigationDestination(for:...)
